# JQuery function attached to Ajax ActionLink

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

Quick question.

I have a Ajax.Action link intended to upload the next section of a form asynchronously.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Next" , "matches",null, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,HttpMethod = "GET"}, new { @class = "button" })
```

I've applied my "button" class to it, which gives it the appearance of a big button. 
I'm looking to attach a JQuery .click event to the above AjaxAction link triggering a function that will hide the previous form.  I'm using the JQuery below to do so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).closest("a.button").click(function () {
            $("form.common").hide();
        });

    });
</script>
```

This is not working for me. The Ajax.ActionLink works fine, just not the Jquery. Below is rough breakdown of my page.

```
<form class="common"> (this form needs to hide)
    //lots of inputs
 <ActionLink class="button>
</form>

<div id="placeholder">
(this is where the new form will be inserted)
</div>
```

I'm new to C# and JavaScript/JQuery, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using any special events with jQuery, you could call a JS method in the beginning of ajax request performed by ajax link.

Add `OnBegin` property in your link `AjaxOptions` and assign a JS function into it and do the logic in that JS function

**Ajax Link**

```
new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "OnBegin" ... }
```

**JS**

```
function OnBegin() {
    $("form.common").hide();
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score -1):

Try to target your element directly instead of using closest. If you can also use the buttons id or assign a more descriptive class.

```
$("a.action_button").click(function () {
   $("form.common").hide();
});
```

Comment: The class name is `button` - scroll the code to the right to see it ;)

Comment: I know I'm just saying that to target the button directly name it accordingly since you could have a many buttons with the class button in many cases.

Comment: But you're selecting links with the class `action_button` in your example.  That's not the class name of the link.  It should be 'a.button'

Comment: I'm selecting a link with the class action_button on it. It literally means that I'm selecting that link or links that have that class and no other. "button" as a class name is extremely generic most css frameworks use it for styling the links as buttons so you should never rely on using that class as a selector.